# How to delete messages posted to slack after sometime?

Tags: api, chatbot, slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I have a slack bot that is sending direct messages to users. I want to add a functionality that will delete the message automatically 10 minutes after it has been sent. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an api that is used to delete chat messages :

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete

For your use case, you need to capture the channel & timestamp details from the response of message that was sent. Once the message is sent, wait for required time and then call 'chat.delete' api to delete the message.

Comment: I am using AWS lambda so how could I wait and use the chat.delete in AWS lambda as everything is instantaneous in aws lambda.

Comment: Can you use SQS queues ? you can add the message timestamp and channel id to the queue and execute it after scheduled time using another lambda.  Check this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Comment: The maximum time limit to delay messages on sqs is 15 minutes only. What if I need to delay it by one hour?

Comment: Your question states 10 mins and I gave you an answer for that. Please mark it as ‘accepted answer’ if you find it useful.